# вывод кириллицы в php через cron

Tags: php, cron, cp1251

Есть php файл, в нем прописано:

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
 </head>
```

Делается запрос к базе и выводится `echo` c кириллицей.

```
echo 'всего строк: ', $st;
```

Если открывать этот файл вручную, то русский язык на странице отображается норм, если запускать через cron то вместо кириллицы знаки вопроса (????? ?????: 1612).

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Во-первых, у вас не закрыта скобка во второй строке >. Во-вторых, где здесь кириллица?

Comment: поправил закрывающую скобку в вопросе. если проблема сохранилась, то напишите что выводит. а так браузер мог сам закрыть тег, чего крон не делает.

Comment: поправил вопрос, скобка была закрыта, видимо плохо скопировал. Проблема осталась.

Comment: Что и куда у вас выводится при запуске через крон?

Comment: как именно вы открываете файл вручную (через блокнот или браузер)? куда выводятся данные при запуске через крон (как понимаю, там отрабатывает php-скрипт)?

Comment: вручную открываю через браузер. В нем кодировка нормальная. cron выполняет php скрипт, да, после выполнения на почту посылает эту же страницу, и там кодировка слетает.

Comment: *вручную открываю через браузер. В нем кодировка нормальная* — потому что браузер перекодирует из той кодировки, что указана в тэге meta, в кодировку вашей локали (вероятно, либо utf-8, либо ucs-2, либо utf-16). *и там кодировка слетает* — не «слетает», конечно, а отображается «так, как есть» («as is»), без всякой перекодировки типа той, что делает браузер. вы ведь получаете **текстовое** письмо, а не вложенный в письмо html-файл, верно? вот ваш почтовый клиент ничего и не перекодирует.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас проблема с кодировкой на сервере или в PHP. Попробуйте для начала выставить в файле .htaccess требуемую кодировку вручную:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

А также пропишите в файл PHP:

```
php_value default_charset "cp1251";
```

Если дело в электронных письмах, то выставляйте при их отправке кодировку:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
```

P.S. И на будущее - переходите на UTF-8, т.к. с кодировками ASCII будет еще немало проблем, особенно при использовании современных web-технологий (AJAX, WebSockets).